# How do I add my photo to my account in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I've seen other users have their own picture in Outlook 2010.  How do I add this to my account?  I don't see anything in Options/Settings.  I've been able to do this in Lync, but not in Outlook.

Comment: Have a look in File > Options > Contacts

Comment: That doesn't work.  I checked before ever posting this.  Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote

Comment: Thanks.  I was asking why to anyone in general, but I realize it's confusing when crammed into a short comment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I ended-up getting this to work by changing my profile pic on our OWA site (accessible at portal.microsoftonline.com) .  Then, in Outlook, I synchronized my offline address book and voila.

Answer (score 21):

Per the [TechNet blogs](http://blogs.technet.com/b/hub/archive/2010/06/01/add-a-picture-to-your-mails-in-outlook-2010.aspx), here is an easy way to add the picture:

> To add a picture (if your organization supports it), click on your
>   name in an e-mail addressed to you. This is the fastest way to open
>   your Contact preview. Click Open Contact to display your full contact
>   information. Now double-click the generic picture icon:

[image]

> You'll be prompted to locate the picture you want to use. Find
>   something appropriate for work, ideally a recent close up of your
>   face. Then click Save & Close and you're done.

Comment: That doesn't work for me.  I think it must be something that an admin has to do at the Exchange/Server level.  Thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: I have Outlook 2010, and when I *double* click my name in an email (single click does nothing) it pops up my contact card. There is *no* "Open Contact" button or option anywhere.

Comment: This worked for me but I had to get to it from a different route: 1. Go to Contacts view of Outlook 2. Search for my name 3. Double-click my contact card in the search results. This takes me to the "Contact Preview" screen shown in the screenshot above.

Answer (score 8):

I wasn't able to double click as described above:

> To add a picture (if your organization supports it), click on your name in an e-mail addressed to you. This is the fastest way to open your Contact preview. Click Open Contact to display your full contact information. Now double-click the generic picture icon:

What I did instead was to got to

1. Contacts (folder below Mail and Calendar folders)
2. Add myself as a contact.

In the processing of adding myself as a contact, I was able to upload my picture.

Comment: But will your picture show up for everyone else at your company?  In other words, if you email John Doe, will he see your picture in his Outlook?

Comment: Tried, does not work. Only works for yourself, which doesn't help much.

Comment: I added myself as a contact from an email addressed to me. Not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on exchange version actually.  2007 doesn't have any normal graphical way to add the picture, so it has to be done via powershell.  If it's 2010 there's a way to add via GUI.  So: Which version of exchange are we talking about?

Comment: They indicated 2010 in the title, the body of the question and tag it as such.

Comment: exchange 2010 does not = outlook 2010

Comment: Gotcha. My bad.

Comment: I've seen the articles mentioning the PowerShell command, but does that need run on the actual Exchange server, or can I just run it from my client workstation?  So far, I've had no such luck from my workstation.  Thanks

Comment: yes, it'd need to be run on the exchange server, and with exchange administrator rights.  unfortunately that means this is out of reach for a lot of normal users who are on exchange 2007 servers.

Comment: @DanielAgans Do you want to update the answer now that you know the version number? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to get this working :

1. Go to Contacts section in your mailbox (under Calender folder)
2. Add my own contact in there
3. Double Click on Generic Pic icon
4. Uploaded my pic
5. Click on Save & Close option in the Header

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, click on the Windows symbol on the bottom left hand side of the screen.

Your user icon will appear on the left hand side, above the four other icons.
Click on this and click 'Change Account Settings'.
 You can set a profile photo here, which will be reflected on Outlook 2010.