# Remove account-associated profile picture in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, microsoft-office-2007

Our company account/email-address is showing a profile picture in outgoing mails. So if I send a mail to someone, that person will see the picture right next to the email address in the header of that mail.

Someone added this picture some time ago, I don't know how, but it's not very professional and needs to be removed.

We use MS Outlook 2007. I've looked around in the settings and Googled for how to do this, but no luck. Does anyone know how to **remove the profile picture/avatar that is somehow associated to our email account**?

*P.s. our other email addresses don't seem to show this picture, so it must be associated to this specific account.*

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, this picture is only visible to those inside of your organization or other organizations that you are federated with.

Outlook relies on Active Directory to pull these pictures from and present them to end users.  There is an attribute in AD called `ThumbnailPhoto` that stores these pictures.  You can always ask your administrator to remove or change the picture associated with that AD user account if you do not have access yourself to these settings.  The following set of instruction are taken from [here](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/networking/how-to-manage-employee-photographs-with-active-directory/5740).

**How to import photos to AD**

There is a minor schema change required to enable use of photos in AD. The change is to flip the thumbnailPhoto attribute to make it replicate to the Global Catalog. Exchange 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1) automatically performs this schema change, so if you have deployed Exchange 2010 SP1, you do not need to make a schema change. Otherwise, you do need to follow these steps:

If you haven’t registered the Schema MMC snap-in on the server you want to make this change on, go ahead and do so using the following command: Regsvr32 schmmgmt.dll
Open an MMC console (Start | Run | MMC) and add the Schema snap-in.
In the Active Directory Schema snap-in, expand the Attributes node, and then locate the thumbnailPhoto attribute.
In the Properties page, select Replicate this attribute to the Global Catalog, and click OK.
Then you are ready to import photos into AD. This is done with a Powershell command.

**Example:**

> Import-RecipientDataProperty -Identity "Dollie Madison" -Picture
>   -FileData ([Byte[]]$(Get-Content -Path "C:\pictures\DollieMadison.jpg" -Encoding Byte -ReadCount 0))

The recommended thumbnail photo size is 96×96 pixels, and by default, the maximum size of photo that can be imported with the Import-RecipientDataProperty command is 10-KB. There are also options to force inclusion of the photo in the offline address book, see the ‘links for more information’ below on how to make those and other advanced changes related to AD photos.

[Here is another resource for updating your Active Directory photo's.](http://blog.cjwdev.co.uk/2010/11/03/the-thumbnailphoto-attribute-explained/)

Comment: I'm afraid not, when I send a mail to my personal email address (not associated with the general company email address), I see it too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though, but it's rather complicated. I know nothing of commands, for example, all I would like is to find the option in Outlook 2007 to change/remove the picture. After all, one of my colleagues (none of them are any bit computer-technical) has put up this picture like this as well..

Comment: The ability to add/change your picture is controlled by whoever runs your Exchange server so you will need to talk to them if you are not able to change your pictrue through OWA.  Take a look a these instructions:  http://help.outlook.com/en-us/140/hh674727.aspx

Comment: You may also take a look at this:  http://superuser.com/questions/500095/how-do-i-add-my-photo-to-my-account-in-outlook-2010

Comment: Updating the picture on AD does not update it on the computer.